# Php page working by oneself but I cant get result of php page with ajax as dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't know anything about ajax but i need solution.I would appreciate it if someone knowledgeable could help.I'm trying call php page by selection.Everything working well but except last result.This is uncertain number selection field.Its can be 3-4 selection fields or 10 selection fields with options.Page working by oneself but i can't show that result in target page using ajax.I should post catid and get the result of get-values.php inside of .Someone can help me ?

I'm trying the code below with .load() and .html() but its not working.

```
function GetCatVal(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./php/get-values.php",
        data:'catid='+val,
        success: function(data){
              
             HELLPPPPPP  sounds are getting louder from this area

    });
}
```

Comment: _I don't know anything about ajax_ therefore research and a bit of learning is required

Comment: _Its can be 3-4 selection fields or 10 selection fields_ Sounds like you need a loop. But if you show us the PHP code we woul dnot have to guess what was being returned from that code

Answer (score 0):

would be nice to get more information where your code fails: in PHP or in ajax, do your get data in PHP or don't even reach PHP code. Did you checked are you getting your `'catid='+val` value in PHP code? I would recommend `console.log(data)` in `success` function.

- `var_dump($_POST);`
- `F12 -> network -> find your get-values.php`

Also i would suggest:

`var param = "catid"+val`

`data: {catid: param}`
Then in PHP you will get `$_POST['catid']`

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is only select> tag.Code page working by oneself but i cant show result inside of div> tag.

```
<select name="kat2" id="kat2-list" onChange="GetCatVal(this.value);">
            <option>Select Category</option>
        </select>


      <div id="katvallist"> </div>
```

php file

```
  ...............
$total2 = $response2->categoryProductAttributeList->categoryProductAttribute->count();
curl_close($curl);


for($i=0; $i<$total2; $i++) { 
..................
echo "<label value=".$attid.">".$response2->categoryProductAttributeList->categoryProductAttribute[$i]->name."</label>";
echo "<select>";
```

-----------------Codes for Collecting Data from API------------------

---After to other selections i should show category attribute names and values.First loop for gather attribute names.This loop creating  tags.Inside of this loop i have secondary loop for gather attribute values.Below echo giving that result to me as fine.-----

```
echo "<option value=".$attlistid.">".$attlistname."</option>";
```

script

```
function GetCatVal(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
    url: "./php/get-values.php",
    data:'catid='+val,

    success: function(data){
        $("#katvallist").html(data);

    }
});
}
```

If i try change some php code for show results inside of select tag its working fine.I can show result to select id="katvallist"> with only creating options> in php codes. but i cant show any data inside of div id="katvallist"> tag.